# Compass App Roll/Y value not changing while device is mounted on a moving Vehicle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-sensors

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help figure this out.

I'm new to Android Dev and created a Compass App to help determine heading in degrees using the device sensors. The Compass returns the right value when the device itself is rotated(while stationary), but when it's mounted in a vehicle the rotation values remain unchanged. I've checked other implementations of the Compass App and there doesn't seem to be anything I'm missing out.

Any insight on what might be the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {


private SensorManager mySensorManager;
private float[] accelVals = new float[3];
private float[] magVals = new float[3];
private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] orientationVals = new float[3];
int Pose;

TextView displayData2;
Sensor myMagneticSensor, myAccelerometer;

// System display. Need this for determining rotation.
private Display mDisplay;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    displayData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data2);

    mySensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(
            Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    myAccelerometer = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    myMagneticSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
            Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);


 }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Listeners for the sensors are registered in this callback and
    // can be unregistered in onStop().
    //
    // Check to ensure sensors are available before registering listeners.
    // Both listeners are registered with a "normal" amount of delay
    // (SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL).

    if (myAccelerometer != null) {
        mySensorManager.registerListener(this, myAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    if (myMagneticSensor != null) {
        mySensorManager.registerListener(this, myMagneticSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // Unregister all sensor listeners in this callback so they don't
    // continue to use resources when the app is stopped.
    mySensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}



    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: {
                accelVals = event.values.clone();
                break;
            }
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD: {
                magVals = event.values.clone();
                break;
            }

        }

        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelVals,
                magVals);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationVals);
        // Convert the result from radians to degrees
        orientationVals[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[0]);
        orientationVals[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[1]);
        orientationVals[2] = (float) (Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[2]) + 360) % 360 ;

        Pose = Math.round(orientationVals[2]);

        //Print Data
        displayData2.setText("Pose: " + Pose);

       // displayData2.setText("Z: " + Float.toString(orientationVals[2]));



    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for the above problem, by implementing the composite Rotation_Vector Sensor instead, retrieving the Rotation Matrix by parsing the vector values into the ".getRoationMatrixFromVector" method, as shown below.

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values);
```

The rotationMatrix values from the alternative process described above seem to be relative to the Earth's Coordinate System, as opposed to the that of the device when stationary.